# jQuery/CSS - Change css class on hover on elements with same href

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I have two separate ULs as menus. I'd like the second menu items to change text color when I hover the first menu items. Maybe a solution where the links with the same href as the link you hovered change css class? How could I do that with jQuery?

```
<ul class="firstMenu jQueryHover">
 <li><a href="href1">bla</a></li>
 <li><a href="href2">bla2</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="secondMenu">
 <li><a href="href1">blabla (same href as firstMenu item you hovered changes this elements css class)</a></li>
 <li><a href="href2">blabla (same href as firstMenu item you hovered changes this elements css class)</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to affect all the links with the same `href`, including the one that was hovered over:

```
$("a").hover(function() {
    $("a[href='" + $(this).attr("href") + "']").addClass("yourClass"); 
}, function() {
    $("a[href='" + $(this).attr("href") + "']").removeClass("yourClass");
});
```

This makes use of the [attribute name selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), to find all links with the same `href` as the currently hovered link.

Here's a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/HDSnC/).

If you wanted to make it so only the other links change (and not the hovered one) then you can make use of the jQuery [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method to exclude the hovered element. It's not clear from your question whether you want all links with the same `href` to change, or all other links but not the currently hovered one.

```
$("a").hover(function() {
    $("a[href='" + $(this).attr("href") + "']").not(this).addClass("yourClass");
}, function() {
    $("a[href='" + $(this).attr("href") + "']").not(this).removeClass("yourClass");
});
```

Comment: amazing! thanks! and yes, it's the second one I need (where only the second menu changes) .. but how could I modify this to work on classes instead, and it should add and remove a class instead of hardcoding a css color value? http://jsfiddle.net/HDSnC/4/

Comment: @Emin - Have another look, I've changed it. Sorry, left it as `css` when copying from the fiddle (I just couldn't be bothered to write CSS classes for them!) but meant to change it to `addClass` and `removeClass`.

Comment: Ok, thats fine. But what I meant was, how can I use class names as triggers to link the two menus items together. Take a look at this link and you will understand what I'm trying to do :) http://jsfiddle.net/HDSnC/4/

Comment: Ahh I think I know what you mean. See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/HDSnC/5/

Comment: Yea, thats it. But there is a little bug with the first item on the second menu (the one with two css classes). And when I run this on my website I get this error in the console: "Error: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .", and the class adding doesn't work (but it seems to work on jsFiddle). http://jsfiddle.net/HDSnC/6/

Answer (score 2):

To change all anchor tags with the same href

```
$("a").hover(function() {
    $("a[href='" + $(this).attr("href") + "']").addClass("hover-class-name"); 
}, function() {
    $("a[href='" + $(this).attr("href") + "']").removeClass("hover-class-name");
});
```

However, I can not see why you want to have two links with the same href on the page? Have you thought about using class names rather than the href to link the anchors?

Comment: I think he wants to animate another part of the page when a link gets hovered on.

Comment: Yes. Class names as triggers instead of href attributes would probably be smarter :) How do I do that?

Comment: Just the same as the example above but replace the `href` with `class` see here for a working example http://jsfiddle.net/wRLG7/

Answer (score 2):

Should be simple:

```
$(".jQueryHover a").hover(function(){
   if($(this).hasClass("hovering"))
      {
         $(this).removeClass("hovering");
         $('a[href="'+$(this).attr('href')+'"]').removeClass("hovering");
      }
   else {
      $(this).addClass("hovering");
      $('a[href="'+$(this).attr('href')+'"]').addClass("hovering");
   }
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nivas/GVuGx/)

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
$('.firstMenu ').hover(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.secondMenu  a[href='+href+']').addClass('newClass');
},
function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.secondMenu  a[href='+href+']').removeClass('newClass');
}
);
```